# MIDI division in the header chunk

Tags: midi, division, bit

The last word of a MIDI header chunk specifies the division. It contains information about whether delta times should be interpreted as ticks per quarter note or ticks per frame (where frame is a subdivision of a second). If bit 15 of this word is set then information is in ticks per frame. Next 7 bits (bit 14 through bit 8) specify the amount of frames per second and can contain one of four values: -24, -25, -29, or -30. (they are negative)

Does anyone know whether the bit 15 counts towards this negative value? So the question is, are the values which specify fps actually 8 bits long (15 through 8) or are they 7 bit long(14 through 8). The documentation I am reading is very unclear about this, and I can not find info anywhere else.

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this?: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MMA's Standard MIDI-File Format Spec says:

> The third word, <division>, specifies the meaning of the delta-times.
>   It has two formats, one for metrical time, and one for time-code-based
>   time:
>
> ```
> +---+-----------------------------------------+
> | 0 |        ticks per quarter-note           |
> ==============================================|
> | 1 | negative SMPTE format | ticks per frame |
> +---+-----------------------+-----------------+
> |15 |14                   8 |7              0 |
> ```
>
> [...]
>   If bit 15 of <division> is a one, delta times in a file correspond
>   to subdivisions of a second, in a way consistent with SMPTE and MIDI
>   Time Code. Bits 14 thru 8 contain one of the four values -24, -25, -29,
>   or -30, corresponding to the four standard SMPTE and MIDI Time Code
>   formats (-29 corresponds to 30 drop frome), and represents the
>   number of frames per second. These negative numbers are stored in
>   two's complement form. The second byte (stored positive) is the
>   resolution within a frame [...]

[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation allows to sign-extend negative values without changing their value by adding a MSB bit of value 1.
So it does not matter whether you take 7 or 8 bits.

In practice, this value is designed to be interpreted as a signed 8-bit value, because otherwise it would have been stored as a positive value.